# Nutch crawling with seeds urls are in range

Tags: nutch, web-crawler

Some site have url pattern as `www.___.com/id=1` to `www.___.com/id=1000`. How can I crawl the site using nutch. Is there any wway to provide seed for fetching in range??

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way would be to have a script to generate your initial list of urls.

Answer (score 0):

no. you have inject them manually or using a script